# MOSS 2007 custom theme in SPS 2010

Tags: theme

Need to ask few things

my scenario is that i have copied my custom theme developed in 2007 to new SPS 2010 folder and attached my content DB from MOSS 2007 to SPS 2010.

the website is opening fine in V3 mode. I used preview option to check how it will appear using new UI features and found all images, styles etc. are lost as it is no longer referring to my custom theme.

what is the easiest way if want to have same look of my site but with new features of SPS 2010.

do i have to convert my 2007 theme in 2010 theme? OR

create new master page and brand it from scratch? OR something else

please note that we have 3 web apps in our 2007 farm using the same custom theme although there is some difference in master pages.

will there be any difference if my site collection is of "publishing" type or "Team site"?

thanks

Mohsin

Answer (score 1):

All of the classes and markup on the masterpages has changed from 2007 to 2010.  You'll need to look at your CSS for your theme as it pertains to the new markup and adjust it accordingly.